# Iterate over variables (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have variables
`experience_company_1, experience_position_1,`
`experience_company_2, experience_position_2,....`

How do I apply a for loop to these variables?
What I tried:

```
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
   console.log(experience_company_ + i)
}
```

but not working.

Note: These are the values of axios response.

Comment: Seems like you want to use an array. You could technically get it to work with `eval('experience_company_' + i)` but it's bad practice to do so.

Comment: *"These are the values of axios response"* - Is that response actually code as you imply, or is that response JSON data?  If the former, that is a *very strange* API and you may need to consult with whomever owns/maintains the API.  If the latter, what is the actual data?

Comment: What type of data you have in these variables ? Its a JSON,  number or string ?

Comment: You should keep those variables in an array instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should use an `array` in cases like these. However, if you do want to go with your approach, you can use `eval()` and [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
for(let i = 1; i < 5; i++){
  exp_var = eval(`experience_company_${i}`);
  console.log(exp_var);
}
```

**Caution: `eval()` is evil and is not recommended.**

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```js
var experience_company_1 = 'Company 1',
    experience_position_1 = 'Position 1',
    experience_company_2 = 'Company 2',
    experience_position_2 = 'Position 2';
[
  experience_company_1,
  experience_position_1,
  experience_company_2,
  experience_position_2
].forEach(value => {
  console.log(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use a jso structure :

```js
var experience = 
  { company_1 : 'c-1' , position_1: 'p-1'
  , company_2 : 'c-2' , position_2: 'p-2'
  , company_3 : 'c-3' , position_3: 'p-3'
  , company_4 : 'c-4' , position_4: 'p-4'
  , company_5 : 'c-5' , position_5: 'p-5'
  }

experience.position_2 = 'something else'

for(let i=1;i<6;++i)
  {
  console.log(experience['company_'+i], experience['position_'+i] )
  }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```